# Check for a substring in C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, character

This is for some added functionality that I need to build into an existing library. I am trying to to check if a string contains a substring. I have pointers to the start and one-past-the-end of the main string,(which is a substring of a much larger string) and the word to search for is a String datatype.

```
char * start;
char * end;
String wordtosearchfor
```

I read about find in C++, but I am having trouble figuring out how to work with the pointer inputs. Is there an inbuilt function that works with inputs in this form? Or would it be efficient to read from start to end into a new String that can be used with find?

Thanks!

Comment: C as in your question title, or C++ as in your tag?

Comment: If `*end` points to either the null terminator corresponding with `*start`, or to the byte immediately preceding it (i.e., you're not searching for a substring within some larger substring of something else), you can simply use `strstr()` if a C function works for you.

Comment: Since the library has String definitions, I understand that it is C++.  Anything that does the job quickly would be great. *end is not the null terminator, the main string to be search is itself a substring of a larger string. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can indeed use member function find of class std::string. For example

```
char * start;
char * end;
std::string wordtosearch;

// setting values for variables

std::string::size_type n = wordtosearch.find( start, 0, end - start );
```

Also there is standard algorithm `std::search` declared in header `<algorithm>`
For example

```
char * start;
char * end;
std::string wordtosearch;

// setting values for variables

std::string::iterator it = std::search( wordtosearch.begin(), wordtosearch.end(), 
                                        start, end );
```

In these examples I suppose that end points after the last character of seached substring.

Comment: Wouldn't this search in wordtosearch? I need to look for wordtosearch in a string that starts at *start and ends at *end-1

Comment: @ame Yes as I have understood this will search in wordtosearch. However if you need to search wordtosearch in some other string there is no a bif difference. It is even simpler.